# Multithreading: passing different custom control properties between threads (or using them asynchronously)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to develop a project where I can have multiple clients making their own server requests for the purpose of stress testing. I'm having a lot of difficulty figuring out how I can manipulate custom control properties when I make a new thread and want that thread to do the work. I have upwards of 100 controls; so ideally 100 individual clients. The problem is my controls are part of the GUI and I don't know how to allow that thread in question get access from that relative control.

Here's what I have:

```
    // Custom project.class to get access to a custom base of properties created within the tool itself.
        List<custom_control_project.custom_control_widget> controlList = new List<custom_control_project.custom_control_widget>();

    private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    ...// control property initializations

    foreach (var control in controlList)
                {
                    if (control.Enabled)
                    {
                        Thread thread = new Thread(() => StartClient());
                        thread.Start();

                        // Loop until worker thread activates.
                        while (!thread.IsAlive);

                        ... // Ideally the GUI updates would happen from these threads. Simple updates to labels based on status code responses and expected xml parameters received.
                    }
                 }
```

My `StartClient()` is largely based off Microsofts asynchronous socket client example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I was running these clients asynchronously but the program was not my end result. I have made a few changes, including resetting the ManualResetEvents. However, when I run my application, all the controls still run one after the other, and I'd like them to be independent. Do I have the right approach by making new threads with the StartClient()?

Referencing microsofts example, the part I'm most interested in is the `ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)` method:

```
public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

        // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
        private ManualResetEvent connectDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private ManualResetEvent sendDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);

        // The response from the remote device.
        private String response = String.Empty;

        public void StartClient()
        {
            // Connect to a remote device.
            try
            {
                // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
                // The name of the
                // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
                //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("host.contoso.com");
                //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
                //IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

                // Create a TCP/IP socket.
                Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                           SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Connect to the remote endpoint.
                client.BeginConnect(asyncServerHolder, asyncPortHolder,
                                    new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
                connectDone.WaitOne();

                // Send test data to the remote device.
                Send(client, (Upload)); //POST HTTP string + xml parameters
                sendDone.WaitOne();

                // Receive the response from the remote device.
                Receive(client);
                receiveDone.WaitOne();

                // Write the response to the console.
                //MessageBox.Show("Response received : " + response);

                // Release the socket.
                client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();

                // Reset all manual events for next instance.
                connectDone.Reset();
                sendDone.Reset();
                receiveDone.Reset();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete the connection.
                client.EndConnect(ar);

                //MessageBox.Show("Socket connected to " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

                // Signal that the connection has been made.
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Receive(Socket client)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the state object.
                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.workSocket = client;

                // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the state object and the client socket
                // from the asynchronous state object.
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket client = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the remote device.
                int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Get the rest of the data.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                    if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                    {
                        response1 = state.sb.ToString();
                    ///
                    ///
                    ///     **THIS IS WHERE I WANT ALL THE PROCESSING TO BE DONE**
                    ///     **AFTER THE RESPONSE IS COMPLETE!!**
                    ///
                    ///

                    }
                    // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Send(Socket client, String data)
        {
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                             new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

                // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
                int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
                //MessageBox.Show("Sent " + bytesSent + " bytes to server.");

                // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

How am I able to get the relative control from my foreach statement passed into the method and then amend my GUI (invoking somehow?) based on the outcome? Also, is it even possible to make each client independent, and have multiple client to server to client requests simultaneously? That is my main objective.

If this is a far fetched or very discouraged way of attempting this, please say so. Without diving into too much programming jargon (for understanding purposes, I'm fairly new to programming), how would you go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can *sort of* manipulate any control from a different thread by using the `BeginInvoke` function on the control, passing the action you want to execute. The action will be executed on the UI thread.

But your main problem here is that you're failing to [separate the concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). You UI code can for sure make actions happen, but these actions should be distinct from any UI code. You should design your actions in such a way to make them reusable. In other words, if you decide to rewrite your UI from scratch, you should still be able to reuse your actions as-is.

To make this possible, your actions should not reference any UI, they even should not be aware of the existence of any UI. This will make your code more manageable. So extract all that stuff in a different class, and then use something like events for instance to communicate back with the UI. The UI code then would make the `BeginInvoke` call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will look into using events for this. I agree that right now my code is not separated properly. I suppose what you're saying is there's no need to pass relative control properties back and forth and just complete all processing in one method and invoke to the main GUI. I have no clue how to interface events in this context but I will learn.

Comment: You should encapsulate your data into meaningful classes, and the pass that around, instead of passing UI controls.